# new tmux pane not sourcing zshrc file

Tags: zsh, tmux, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

Using iTerm2 with tmux and zsh. I have an issue that new tmux panes doesn't source `~/.zshrc` file

I have customized my terminal (when running `source ~/.zshrc` manually it works) but when opening new pane (`C+b` and `c`) it doesn't source the file

`~/.tmux.conf`

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -g default-command /bin/zsh
set-option -g default-shell /bin/zsh
```

`~/.zshrc`

```
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

plugins=(git tmux)

ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

 if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
   export EDITOR='vim'
 else
   export EDITOR='mvim'
 fi

export TERM=xterm-256color

eval "$(starship init zsh)"
```

iTerm settings
[[image: iTerm settings1]

current terminal (on new pane)
[image: current status]

wanted terminal (on new pane)
[image]

Comment: I suspect this is a login-shell (or not) distinction. What happens if you set the default-command to `"/bin/zsh -l"` and then reload or restart `tmux`?

Comment: Hi do you mean inside the tmux config file right ? tired and still same result

Comment: How did you restart `tmux` and what exactly did you put into `tmux.conf`?

Comment: tmux kill-server and set -g default-command "/bin/zsh -l"

Comment: `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` should be less brutal than `kill-server`. Can you add a `print foo` at the top `~/.zshrc` for diagnostics? In theory it should be being read  by `zsh`. (Maybe oh-my-zsh or whatever `ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true` does complicates matters?)

Comment: That's so weird. added `print foo` in the `~ /.zshrc` file. And now I do see `foo` printed on any new `tmux` pane but it still doesn't load custom terminal. Tried removing `ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true` - same..

Comment: for some reason this line `eval $(starship init zsh)` which is responsible for the custom theme isn't running on new `tmux` pane

Comment: Is that code being reached (add more print statements or trace the shell)? If so, there might be something in your environment that is making `starship` unhappy?

Comment: tried adding `print` before and after - both succeeded. no clue why `starship` isn't working well.. when I run `eval "$(starship init zsh)"` in the new pane manually it works like expected

Comment: hi @thrig any suggestions ?